# Pandas histogram bins alignment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, histogram

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
train_data_10users = pd.DataFrame({'target':['A','A','B', 'B', 'C'], 'day_of_week':[4,2,4,4,1]})

 target  day_of_week
0   A            4
1   A            2
2   B            4
3   B            4
4   C            1
```

and I want to have a histogram of counts by day_of_week for each target, i.e

```
"A" should have:
0,1,3,5,6:0
2,4:1
"B" should have
0,1,2,3,5,6:0
4:2
"C" should have 1:1, the rest:0
```

Here is the pivot table which shows real data that I want to be present on histograms(Note: fillna):

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(train_data_10users,
                       index=["target"], columns=["day_of_week"], aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)

day_of_week 0   1   2   3   4   5   6
target                          
Ashley  390 328 1078    293 115 0   0
Avril   148 402 273 318 87  104 311
Bill    308 239 105 24  54  7   65
Bob 51  285 72  284 330 0   0
```

Even though some of days may be missing in the groupby, adding proper xticks does the trick:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, figsize=(16, 10))
for idx, (user, sub_df) in enumerate(
        pd.groupby(train_data_10users[["target", "day_of_week"]], 'target')): 
    ax = axes[idx // 4, idx % 4]
    sub_df.hist(ax=ax, label=user, color=color_dic.get(user), bins=7)
    ax.set_xticks(range(7))
    ax.legend()
```

But the values are not perfectly aligned/centered, moreover positions are floating a bit, I assume it depends on the number of days present/missing for each target:
[image: hist]

**Upd.**
Here is how it looks according to accepted answer:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, figsize=(16, 10), sharey=True)
...
sub_df.hist(ax=ax, label=user, color=color_dic.get(user), bins=range(8))
ax.set_xticks(range(8))
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(8)+0.5)
ax.set_xticklabels(range(7))
```

[image: hist_result]

Comment: What is `train_data_10users`? What is `axes`?

Comment: It's my dataframe and subplot axes

Comment: For those trying to recreate the dataframe: `train_data_10users = pd.DataFrame({'target':['A','A','B', 'B', 'C'],
                 'day_of_week':[4,2,4,4,1]})`

Comment: Can you please show the declaration/initialization of `axes` in your question?

Comment: done, let me also add your train_data definition

Comment: You also need to include the necessary `import` statements, such as `matplotlib` and `color_dict`

Comment: I think I found the solution: ax.set_xticks(range(7))
It does almost what I want, but the bins are not centered in exact positions

Comment: So what do you expect, remove those with zero/NaN off the hist bin? That's not really histogram.

Comment: Let me change the picture now with xticks..stay tuned

Comment: See my edited answer if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, figsize=(16, 10))
for idx, (user, sub_df) in enumerate(
    pd.groupby(train_data_10users[["target", "day_of_week"]], 'target')): 
    ax = axes[idx // 4, idx % 4]

    # note bin is forced to range(7)
    sub_df.hist(ax=ax, label=user, bins=range(7))

    # offset the xticks
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(7) + .5)

    # name the label accordingly
    ax.set_xticklabels(range(7))
```

Output with `bins=range(7)`:
[image]

Comment: Note I also change `bins` to `range(7)`. It's a little different from `bins=7` as `bins=7` divided range `min-max` by 7 bins, while the formal set it specifically to `(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)`

Comment: Yes, I noticed that and deleted my prev comment. However there is still a little issue. 
Now, the hist is kinda sifted to the right and it doesn't draw value for first day. Let me post the picture as Upd.

Comment: change offset to `+0.5``.

Comment: I tried, but it just does the opposite, with +0.5 it will not show values for the last day..

Comment: Found the problem, change  `bins=range(8)`. Also, consider putting `sharey=True` to `subplots`.